# How to make WakefulService (IntentService) wait until MediaPlayer finishes?

Tags: android, media-player, intentservice

I'm trying to make an app, which plays series of sounds using MediaPlayer, at scheduled times. To properly handle the wake lock and schedule the playback I used [CommonsWare's WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Unfortunately, the IntentService's worker thread quits right after I call `MediaPlayer.play()` and neither MediaPlayer registered listeners are called. Instead, the exception is logged:

```
W/MessageQueue(6727): Handler (android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler) {4160d820} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(6727): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler) {4160d820} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(6727):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:294)
W/MessageQueue(6727):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
W/MessageQueue(6727):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
W/MessageQueue(6727):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
W/MessageQueue(6727):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.postEventFromNative(MediaPlayer.java:2063)
W/MessageQueue(6727):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

As far as I understand, it is caused by the worker thread being already dead when MediaPlayer completes. If I pause the thread by means of the debugger and let the player complete, everything works fine.

In my listeners I not only release MediaPlayer's resources, but also use OnCompletionListener to do consecutive `MediaPlayer.play()` calls until the sound queue is empty.

I tried putting a wait loop right after the initial `play()` call, checking for a custom completion flag, but it seems to freeze because MediaPlayer's callbacks are called on the same thread `play()` was called.

The question is, how can I make the worker thread not quit before I let it do so (i.e. the has been processed and the `onCompletion()` method has been called for the last time?

Here is the code of my service:

```
public class SoundService extends WakefulIntentService {
    private static final TAG = "SoundService";
    private final Queue<SoundDescriptor> soundQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<SoundDescriptor>();

    private final OnCompletionListener onComediaPlayerletionListener = new OnComediaPlayerletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                if (!playNextFromQueue(mediaPlayer)) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Reached end of queue. Cleaning up.");
                    release();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception!", e)
                release();
            }
        }
    };
    private final OnErrorListener onErrorListener = new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Error!!");
            release();
            return false;
        }
    };

    public SoundService() {
        // populate soundQueue
    }

    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnComediaPlayerletionListener(onComediaPlayerletionListener);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(onErrorListener);
        playNextFromQueue(mediaPlayer);
    }

    private boolean playNextFromQueue(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
        SoundDescriptor descriptor = soundQueue.poll();
        if (descriptor != null) {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> To properly handle the wake lock and schedule the playback I used CommonsWare's WakefulIntentService.

That's not an appropriate choice.

> Unfortunately, the IntentService's worker thread quits right after I call MediaPlayer.play() and neither MediaPlayer registered listeners are called.

That's why it's not an appropriate choice. :-)

> The question is, how can I make the worker thread not quit before I let it do so (i.e. the has been processed and the onCompletion() method has been called for the last time?

Don't use `WakefulIntentService`. Don't use `IntentService`. Use `Service`. Manage the `WakeLock` yourself, and call `stopSelf()` on the service when the audio is finished.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a correct answer. I hoped WakefulIntentService would help me fix the problem with ICS, where the alarms get unregistered because my application is killed by the system.

Comment: @ohaleck: "where the alarms get unregistered because my application is killed by the system" -- alarms do not "get unregistered because my application is killed by the system" on any version of Android. Alarms *will* "get unregistered" if the user Force Stops your application from the Settings app.

Comment: My app is already on Google Play and I keep receiving complaints that it stops working after different periods of time (hours or days). It is always on Android 4.0+ and no app killer or manual force stopping is involved.

Comment: @ohaleck: "I keep receiving complaints that it stops working after different periods of time (hours or days)" -- technically, that does not mean that your alarms are getting unregistered. Unless most users are having this problem, your issue is not that your "application is killed by the system", because your process is going to be terminated with some frequency. It will not last for days on many devices.

Comment: Actually it behaves just the same on one of my ICS devices, but I am unable to find the reason. Is there any way to make AlarmManager alarms really reliable? Two remote services keeping an eye on each other?

Comment: @ohaleck: "Is there any way to make AlarmManager alarms really reliable?" -- AFAIK, it *is* "really reliable". If you sense that your alarms are not happening on some device that you can reach, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to dump the outstanding alarms and see if your app shows up.

Comment: I guess it's not a good place to continue this discussion, but I'll ask my last question. `adb shell dumpsys alarm` lists my alarm (it is a recurring one) and after a random period of time it disappears. It resembles the situation described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249555/737885. Is there a way to catch the very event in order to have it do something to help me find out the reason (like: dump a stacktrace)?

Comment: @ohaleck: "after a random period of time it disappears" -- on an undisturbed device (i.e., no one messing with Force Stop)? Do you have any code that might `cancel()` the alarm that perhaps due to a bug is being executed when you're not expecting it? Outside of those two scenarios, plus a reboot, there is nothing that should get rid of an alarm. We're then down to things like firmware bugs. "Is there a way to catch the very event" -- well, if it is `cancel()`, you're the one calling it. In the other cases (Force Stop and reboot), no, you cannot catch the event.

Comment: @CommonsWare The problem here is that the MediaPlayer caches a handler to the thread that creates it, in case it had a looper, otherwise uses the main thread. It uses this handler to run the listeners. So even with a dedicated service, if the thread that created the player is gone, then the listeners don't run.

Comment: @MisterSmith: Have your service create its own `HandlerThread`. If you have further questions on this, ask a fresh SO question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with MediaPlayer is that it caches a Handler to the current thread when it is instantiated. In case the current thread has no Looper, it defaults to the main thread. It will use this handler to execute the listeners callbacks.

Lets say you instantiate the player and use it inside a service's thread. If you call the player methods through the service, and then this service thread dies, the player will try to call the callbacks to the registered listeners using a handler pointing to the deceased thread, and it will throw the exception shown in the question.

I've find MediaPlayer very tricky and unreliable. The simplest solution is to use the player in the main thread. They are short calls, shouldn't raise ANR's.